# pass awk calculation results to variables

Tags: variables, awk

Let's say we have an input file_789

```
1
1
1
```

Is there any way that we could output the awk counting results into variables so that we can print out the following?

```
Cargo 789 has 3 items
```

Now we try:

```
for cargo in 789

do

awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum}' file_${cargo}  # This will give us a result of "3". 

echo "Cargo ${cargo} has ${calculation} items" 

done
```

Wonder if there is any way to pass the awk one liner result to ${calculation} so echo could do its work?  Thanks~!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `awk` calculation can be stored in a shell variable:

```
calculation=$(awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum}' "file_${cargo}")
```

Or, you can do both the calculating and printing in `awk`:

```
awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print "Cargo '"${cargo}"' has " sum " items"}' "file_${cargo}"
```

Alternatively, we can use `printf` which works better with empty files:

```
awk -v cargo="$cargo" '{sum+=$1} END {printf "Cargo %s has %d items\n", cargo, sum}' "file_${cargo}"
```

Also, the use of the option `-v cargo="$cargo"` simplifies the quoting.

Comment: Note: calculation=$(awk '{ sum+=$1} END {print sum-1}' file_789) only works in bash not tcsh/csh

Comment: @Chubaka - never write scripts in t/csh (google "csh why not") and don't jump in/out of awk as in that second solution. If you want to print the result from awk you'd do `awk -v cargo="$cargo" '{ sum+=$1} END {printf "Cargo %s has %d items\n", cargo, sum}'` which is also one way to protect yourself from your sum being printed as a null string `""` instead of `0` if the file is empty.

Comment: Thanks Ed! I have read that article and totally agree with it.  Unfortunately the default shell of our current cluster is t/csh ><.  I write in bash and ask the user to type "bash" before execute these scripts.

Comment: Can't you write your scripts to invoke bash themselves (e.g with a shebang or equivalent) so people can use t/csh for their interactive shell but write scripts in bash without having to know to call bash when invoking the script?